# Send signature png to PDFotter api

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got this great API for filling pdfs that's called [pdfotter](https://pdfotter.github.io/slate/), I'm looking for someone who used this API before and maybe found a way to fill in a signature in the form.

The signature part is very important and can not be replaced with a simple string for legal reasons.

My request looks like this:

```
let form = {
    signature: fs.createReadStream('1.png'),
    date: new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-gb'), // default
};

request
    .post('https://www.pdfotter.com/api/v1/pdf_templates/.../fill')
    .form({
        data: {
            ...form
        },
    })
    .auth('...', '')
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('result.pdf'));
```

The result in the signature looks like this:

> #ActionController::Paramet ers:0x0000000674cf60>

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this PDFotter service, but anyway I see that your request is formed incorrectly: `form.signature` field is not filled with a suitable value, because you set a stream there.

`signature: fs.createReadStream('1.png')`  <- this will not work in any way.

Try to replace signature with some valid value, for example a string `Michael Ionov`.

```
let form = {
    signature: `Michael Ionov`,
    date: new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-gb'), // default
};
```

I understand that you probably need to paste an image there, but firstly check if it works with 100% valid value.

There is no information on pdfotter web site about sending images, but if you are sure they support it - you will need to try pass to `signature` raw image data using for example `fs.readFileSync('img.png')`, or Base64 encoded image:

```
signature: new Buffer(fs.readFileSync('img.png').toString('base64');
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately the result is a simple string of bytes, I'm afraid they do not expect hat input and might not support it, waiting for their response as well.

Answer (score 0):

So the API providers answered me and there is actually a nice way to do it but is not yet documented, all I needed to do is to prepend 'image:' to the signature field and also prepend it on the form itself in their, and send the image as a base64 string.

```
'image:signature': fs.readFileSync('signature.png').toString('base64')
```

Happy hacking!